# I am modifying Java with Kotlin, but I am struggling to fix the wrong parts(edit )

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

**activity.kotlin**

```
var postsMap = HashMap<>() //Here error
postsMap.put("uid", current_user_id)
postsMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate)
postsMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime)
postsMap.put("description", Description)
postsMap.put("postimage", downloadUrl)
postsMap.put("profileimage", userProfileImage)
postsMap.put("fullname", userFullName)
PostsRef.child(current_user_id + postRandomName).updateChildren(postsMap)//Here error
    .addOnCompleteListener(object : OnCompleteListener {//Here error
        override fun onComplete(task: Task<*>) { //Here error
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                SendUserToMainActivity()
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@PostActivity,
                    "New Post is updated successfully.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@PostActivity,
                    "Error Occured while updating your post.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()

            }
        }
    })
```

sorry for the inaccurate question.
Thank you

I corrected the code through answer. Thank you.

val postsMap: HashMap = hashMapOf()

PostsRef!!.child(current_user_id + postRandomName).updateChildren(postsMap)

Comment: What does your IDE tell you about the underlined parts of code?

Comment: Can you please put the java code too?

Comment: Cuz it should be `val postsMap: HashMap<String, Any?> = hashMapOf()`

Comment: Have you tried to write the code in Java and get Android Studio (I'm assuming you're using Android Studio) to convert the code for you and see how it converts it to understand what's going wrong?

Comment: oh thanks 
I have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap requires type parameters. Change first line to

```
val postsMap = HashMap<String, String>()
```

or

```
val postsMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
```